# Deploying a form-less Windows Forms application as an exe-file

Tags: deployment, winforms

How can you deploy a Windows Forms application to a single **.exe file** so that your users won't have to install your application, but just run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the bin directory of your solution. The raw **.exe-file** is located in the Release directory:

> **[Your solution directory] \ bin \ Release**